# C# add variable to the array

Tags: c#, arrays, wpf

I want to use variable from other functions to array something like that:

```
int arg1 = int.Parse(Textbox1.Text);
int arg2 = int.Parse(Textbox2.Text);
int[] array1 = {arg1, arg2};
```

But it doesn't work please help

I tried something easier

```
int arg1 = 0;
int arg2 = 1;
int[] DaneInt = { arg1, arg2};
```

And still the same error for `arg1` and `arg2`:

> a field initializer cannot reference the nonstatic field method or
>   property

Comment: What doesn't work about that?  The only problem I can is if your textboxes don't contain number strings you will get a FormatException.  You can use TryParse to cover such issues.

Comment: *doesn't work*, why? Explain that so that we can help you further.

Comment: I see somthint like that "a field initializer cannot reference the nonstatic field method or property" it is a WFP FORM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have placed it before the `Constructor`. Any object initializer used outside a `Constructor` has to refer to static members. You got this error because the instance has to be initialized before you can access the properties of its class. You should place your code inside the `Constructor`.

Answer (score 0):

As Jeff pointed out in his comment, the main problem (and the only problem unless you mess up somewhere else) is that you may has passed some non-digit character, which caused the problem. I would recommend that you try it this way using a TryParse(),

```
int[] array1 = new int[2]; // Array of 2 elements
int arg1 = int.TryParse(Textbox1.Text, array1[0]); // At zero index
int arg2 = int.TryParse(Textbox2.Text, array1[1]); // At 1 index
```

This would work, and if it doesn't, good thing that you can show an error message in a way

```
if(int.TryParse(Textbox1.Text, array1[0]) {
   // Worked 
} else {
   // Didn't work
}
```

**Plus**: There is a problem with case-sensitivity in your code. The control TextBox has a field `Text`, not `text`. That is also a problem in your code, you should consider keeping that in mind also.

**Edit**

In your comment you have mentioned that the error that you are getting is, *a field initializer cannot reference the nonstatic field method or property* that means that you are trying to use this variable (IMO; Textbox1) in a separate class or Window. In that case, you cannot use it just the way it is, because it is nonstatic. To reference it, create a class instance,

```
var text = new MainWindow().TextBox1.Text;
```

This will create an instance for the Window (remember, WPF has no Form, it has a Window control) and then it will reference the TextBox control to access the property `Text`.

Comment: I see somthint like that "a field initializer cannot reference the nonstatic field method or property" it is a WFP FORM

Comment: WPF is not a Form, they are different frameworks. You should consider using `var text = new MainWindow().Textbox1.Text;`. Are you using the Textbox value in a separate Window?

Comment: @RafałSularz I have updated the answer, please see the **Edit** section.

Comment: still "a field initializer cannot reference the nonstatic field method or property"

Comment: @RafałSularz, please share the code where this error codes (in the question post).

Answer (score -1):

You are missing the type of the array you want to create using `arg1` and `arg2`.

Add the array type like this: 
`int[] array1 = new int[] { arg1, arg2};`

It should work!

Comment: `new int[]` is redundant code. Code should works with array initializer like `int[] array1 = {arg1, arg2};`!

Comment: I see somthint like that "a field initializer cannot reference the nonstatic field method or property" it is a WFP FORM